# ADT explorer error cant put models into graph view

Tags: syntax-error, azure-digital-twins

i followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/quickstart-adt-explorer) guide to set up the adt explorer. i can upload models into the model view, but i cant put any of them into the graph view. i get this error: Error in instance creation: SyntaxError: unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.

it doesnt seem like there is anything wrong with the models, since they work with an older version of the adt explorer.

is there any of the packages that can cause this problem? or could it be that my pc couldn't do the console installation properly for some reason?

edit: i can put models into the graph view on earlier versions of the adt explorer then close it and start up the latest version again and run query to get the models into the graph view. so the problem seems to be trying to create new twins, straight form the models themselves or by importing graph.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the ADT explorer i think. I can't make it to work. As a workaround, use the az cli ([MS Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-command-line-cli)).

```
az dt twin create -n <ADT_instance_name> --dtmi "<dtmi>" --twin-id <twin-id>
```